# Complex function with two inverses?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I was computing the inverse of the complex function

$$\xi(z) = z + \frac{1}{z} \quad \text{ where } z \ne 0$$

which lead me to a strange conclusion. If we set

$$\xi(\xi^{-1}(z)) = z$$

and solve for $\xi^{-1}$ we get

$$\xi^{-1}(z) = \frac{z \pm \sqrt{z^2 - 4}}{2}$$

and it seems as if it doesn't matter whether I resolve $\pm$ to $+$ or $-$, as $\xi^{-1}$ works as an inverse with either selection. What's going on here?

Comment: Your function is not injective (so it doesn't have a well-defined inverse) unless you restrict its domain of definition.

Comment: @mrf Ok, if I only consider a half plane with the unit disk removed it still seems that I can pick either sign.

Comment: Yes, it appears there are two possible analytic branches for the inverse. This is not completely surprising if you consider the function $z^2$ which has two possible branches for an inverse also, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is not injective (so it doesn't have a well-defined inverse) unless you restrict its domain of definition.

Note that $\xi(z) = \xi(w)$ if and only if
$$
z + \frac1z = w + \frac1w \Leftrightarrow z^2w + w = w^2z + z \Leftrightarrow
(zw-1)(z-w)=0
$$
i.e. if and only if $z=w$ or $z = \frac1w$. To get a unique inverse, you need to restrict $\xi$ to a domain that doesn't contain any pair of points $z,w$ such that $zw=1$. For example you can restrict to the unit disc or to the complement of the unit disc.

(To write down the explict inverse, you also need to choose a suitable branch of the complex square root.)